# Convert system log to csv macOS

Tags: shell, zsh

Given the log line

```
Sep 25 20:10:44 Evans-MacBook-Pro-2 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld[50806]): Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error = 2: No such file or directory, path = /usr/local/mysql: 19H114: xpcproxy + 14537 [673][F3151671-4794-3393-AF04-C3421B7647F3]: 0x2
```

I'd like to convert this to a csv file such that the csv is formatted like so :

```
DATE, SYSTEM, SERVICE, MESSAGE
Sep 25 20:10:44, macbook, com.apple.xpc.launchd[1], (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld[50806]): Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error = 2: No such file or directory, path = /usr/local/mysql: 19H114: xpcproxy + 14537 [673][F3151671-4794-3393-AF04-C3421B7647F3]: 0x2
```

The tricky part here is that the message can contain a comma. I'm starting with the command

```
cat system.log | grep error
```

and building from here. This is almost complete

```
grep error system.log \
| while IFS=' ' read d1 d2 d3 sys svc msg; do
    printf '%s, %s, %s, "%s"\n' "$d1 $d2 $d3" $sys $svc "${msg//\"/\"\"}"
done
```

The only issue is parsing the message
[image]

Comment: You will want to look at the documentation for syslog or journald and output the log in csv to begin with. There really isn't a way to convert the log entries to csv given the messages are not fixed-length fields and there is no guarantee that any one field will contain unique words to use as a token. The date, host, etc. are trivial to convert, the message itself and errors are not.

Comment: In the added screenshot, it appears that your spreadsheet application (Numbers? I don't have it installed on my Mac) is splitting the fields by space instead of by comma.  Some things to try: a) Make sure the file extension of the imported file is .csv. b) Also try it with a .txt extension.  c) Look for the 'adjust settings' button described in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/399222/274760. d) Use a tab-delimited file (I added that to the answer below). e) Try Google Sheets. f) Try LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do this in `zsh` and `bash`:

```
printf 'DATE, SYSTEM, SERVICE, MESSAGE\n'
grep error system.log \
| while IFS=' ' read d1 d2 d3 sys svc msg; do
    printf '%s, %s, %s, "%s"\n' "$d1 $d2 $d3" $sys $svc "${msg//\"/\"\"}"
done
```

This script is based on some assumptions:

- The date, system, and service fields do not have embedded spaces other than what is shown in your example.
- The consumer of the `csv` file can handle the quoting used for the message field.

---

A standard way to support commas in .csv files is to surround the field with double quotes, and then to escape double-quotes by repeating them. The Wikipedia entry on csv files has more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

But while quoting like this is common, it is by no means universal.  If the csv consumer cannot handle quoted files, a simple answer is to change the commas to semi-colons:

```
print 'DATE, SYSTEM, SERVICE, MESSAGE'
grep error system.log \
| while IFS=' ' read -A fl; do
    ary=("$fl[1,3]" "$fl[4]" "$fl[5]" "${fl[6,-1]//,/;}")
    print ${(j:, :)ary}
done
```

Note that this version uses some zsh-specific syntax: `print`, `read -A` to assign values to an array (it also collapses consecutive spaces into a single space), and the `j` (join) parameter expansion flag.

---

Added: some consumers of 'csv' files may work better with tab delimiters.
That's a simple change in `zsh`:

```
printf 'DATE\tSYSTEM\tSERVICE\tMESSAGE\n'
grep error system.log \
| while IFS=' ' read d1 d2 d3 sys svc msg; do
    ary=("$d1 $d2 $d3" "$sys" "$svc" "$msg")
    print ${(pj:\t:)ary}
done
```